# dynamically adding markers to google map - angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, typescript, google-maps-api-3

So I have two components, first of them is just form which I use for adding latitude and longitude to service for markers.
My main component is the map where I want to add markers.
My first problem is that I initialize map and get data in ngOnInit() so I can't dynamically add new data because the component doesn't reload and OnInit don't run again. My second problem is that I don't know how to add new markers when I initialize my map in ngOnInit.

That is my main component:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  parties: Party[] = [];
  party_location: Location[] = [];

 constructor(private partyService: PartyService) { }

 ngOnInit() {
   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
     center: { lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044 },
     scrollwheel: true,
     zoom: 16
  });

   this.parties = this.partyService.getData(); //get my data

   for (let item of this.parties) { //try to add markers
     let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: { lat: item.lan1, lng: item.lan2 },
      title: item.title
      });
    }

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
       navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
         let pos = {
         lat: position.coords.latitude,
         lng: position.coords.longitude
       };

       infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
       infoWindow.setContent('This is you.');
       infoWindow.open(map);
       map.setCenter(pos);
     });
    }

    let infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

  }
 }
```

May be you have some advice how to change my code??